# rosbag: error: Cannot find rosbag/play executable

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running ROS Noetic on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

I cannot run `rosbag play` or `rosbag record`. It was working perfectly last week, but it ceased to work this week. I have tried reinstalling using `apt install ros-noetic-rosbag`, but that didn't help.
The weird thing is `rosbag check` and `rosbag info` work pretty well:

```
rosbag check flight_2022_02_21_23_02_03.bag
Bag file does not need any migrations.
```

I have suppressed the topic names from `rosbag info` so this thread isn't too long, but this is the header in it:

```
rosbag info flight_2022_02_21_23_02_03.bag
path:         flight_2022_02_21_23_02_03.bag
version:      2.0
duration:     1:15s (75s)
start:        Feb 21 2022 17:02:40.34 (1645484560.34)
end:          Feb 21 2022 17:03:56.02 (1645484636.02)
size:         9.9 MB
messages:     90332
compression:  bz2 [101/101 chunks; 10.04%]
uncompressed: 82.3 MB @   1.1 MB/s
compressed:    8.3 MB @ 111.8 KB/s (10.04%)
```

The following happens when I try `rosbag record` or `rosbag play`:

Record:

```
rosbag record -a -O example.bag
Usage: rosbag record TOPIC1 [TOPIC2 TOPIC3 ...]

rosbag: error: Cannot find rosbag/record executable
```

Play:

```
rosbag play flight_2022_02_21_23_02_03.bag
Usage: rosbag play BAGFILE1 [BAGFILE2 BAGFILE3 ...]

rosbag: error: Cannot find rosbag/play executable
```

I know that the problem isn't with the bag, as a coworker was able to play that same bag. I also tried other bags that I could play before, but I can't play any bags whatsoever now. I have noticed that the error was [once observed by one user](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/1037), but there was no solution anywhere that I could find (that user was supposed to open a question in this forum, but I wasn't able to find one).

Here is what I get from the following commands:

Find rosbag:

```
find /opt/ros/noetic/lib/rosbag
/opt/ros/noetic/lib/rosbag
/opt/ros/noetic/lib/rosbag/record
/opt/ros/noetic/lib/rosbag/fixbag_batch.py
/opt/ros/noetic/lib/rosbag/bagsort.py
/opt/ros/noetic/lib/rosbag/encrypt
/opt/ros/noetic/lib/rosbag/fastrebag.py
/opt/ros/noetic/lib/rosbag/play
/opt/ros/noetic/lib/rosbag/fix_moved_messages.py
/opt/ros/noetic/lib/rosbag/topic_renamer.py
/opt/ros/noetic/lib/rosbag/savemsg.py
/opt/ros/noetic/lib/rosbag/makerule.py
/opt/ros/noetic/lib/rosbag/fix_msg_defs.py
/opt/ros/noetic/lib/rosbag/fix_md5sums.py
/opt/ros/noetic/lib/rosbag/fixbag.py
/opt/ros/noetic/lib/rosbag/bag2png.py
```

Rospack find:

```
rospack find rosbag
/home/marcelino/catkin_ws/src/ros_comm/tools/rosbag
```

Any ideas in how I can fix this without having to format my laptop? =)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/396520/rosbag:-error:-cannot-find-rosbag/play-executable/) by [Marcelino Almeida](https://answers.ros.org/users/86491/marcelino-almeida/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2022-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was just able to find the solution, and I hope this will help others in the future.
The issue is that I had `ros_comm` in my catkin workspace, but rosbag wasn't built.
I just went to my catkin workspace, ran `catkin build rosbag`, then I was back in business

---

Originally posted by [Marcelino Almeida](https://answers.ros.org/users/86491/marcelino-almeida/) with karma: 16 on 2022-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0